# No se selecciona el option añadido

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, select2

Veréis, tengo una etiqueta select y al lado un botón al cual añado nuevo items a éste, el problema es que no me selecciona el option que añado.

He probado a imprimir data y no me muestra nada, está vacío, no sé si será este el problema.

Todo lo demás funciona correctamente, me manda los datos a la url, etc.

**HTML**

```
<select class="form-control select select2-hidden-accessible" id="modelo-add" tabindex="-1">
<option></option>
```

**JS**

```
$(".select").select2({
            placeholder: "Seleccionar.."});

            var url = "includes/lists/adds/add-list-modelos.php";
            var dataValue = {'marca': marca, 'modelo': modelo};

            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: url,
                data: dataValue,
                cache: false,
                async: true,
                success: function (data) {
                    setTimeout(function () {
                        $('#modelo-add').append('<option value="'+data+'">'+modelo+' '+marca+'</option>');
                        $('#modelo-add').val(data);
                    }, 200);
                }
            });
```

Comment: Nop, ya he probado todo eso y nada.

Comment: Será porque `dataValue` es un objeto, y cuando se lo pondes al `<option value>` has de especificar qué propiedad quieres añadir: marca, o modelo?

Comment: Perfecto, ese era el problema, ponlo como respuesta y te la doy como correcta, muchas gracias !! :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El fallo estaria cuando le pones `value = "' + data + '"` ya que `data` es un objeto. Deberías especificar qué propiedad añadir: `Marca` o `Modelo`. Y lo mismo al asignar el `val()`

```
success: function (data) {
    setTimeout(function () {
        $('#modelo-add').append('<option value="'+data+'">'+modelo+' '+marca+'</option>');      
        $('#modelo-add').val(data);                 ↑       
    }, 200);                  ↑
}
```

Y tras asignar el valor, añadir un `change()` para que se seleccione esa opcion:

```
$('#modelo-add').val(data).change();
```